Java Swing Custom zoom Panel
I am experiencing an issue with the zoom panel action in Java Swing. I have customized a class ZoomableJPanel to zoom innerPanel, but the ZoomableJPanel does not correctly handle zooming, causing the content to overflow beyond its boundaries. Calling repaint() in the parent class only schedules the repaint and does not execute it immediately, which fails to resolve the issue.
public class ZoomableJPanel extends JPanel implements MouseWheelListener, MouseListener, MouseMotionListener, KeyListener, PropertyChangeListener {

    private Panel innerPanel;

    private double zoomFactor = 1;
    private double prevZoomFactor = 1;
    private boolean zoomer;
    private boolean dragger;
    private boolean released;
    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;
    private int xDiff;
    private int yDiff;
    private int xZoom;
    private int yZoom;
    private Point startPoint;
    private final CustomCallback callBack;

    public ZoomableJPanel(Panel innerPanel, CustomCallback callback) {
        this.innerPanel = innerPanel;
        this.callBack = callback;
        initComponent();
        setLayout(null);
        add(innerPanel);
        setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        setFocusable(true);
        requestFocusInWindow();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setComponentZOrder(innerPanel, getComponentCount() - 1);
        innerPanel.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                revalidate();
                repaint();
                revalidate();
            }
        });
    }

    private void initComponent() {
        addMouseWheelListener(this);
        addMouseMotionListener(this);
        addMouseListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        addKeyListener(this);
    }

    public void setInnerPanel(Panel innerPanel) {
        this.innerPanel = innerPanel;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        AffineTransform at = new AffineTransform();

        if (zoomer) {
            double xRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX();
            double yRel = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY();

            double zoomDiv = zoomFactor / prevZoomFactor;

            xOffset = zoomDiv * (xOffset - xRel) + xRel;
            yOffset = zoomDiv * (yOffset - yRel) + yRel;

//            at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
//            at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
            prevZoomFactor = zoomFactor;
        } else if (dragger) {
            at.translate(xOffset + xDiff, yOffset + yDiff);
            at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);

            if (released) {
                xOffset += xDiff;
                yOffset += yDiff;
                dragger = false;
            }
        } else {
            at.translate(xOffset, yOffset);
            at.scale(zoomFactor, zoomFactor);
        }
        if (zoomer) {
            callBack.execute();
            zoomer = false;

        }
//        g2.setTransform(at);
//        innerPanel.paint(g2);
        updateInnerPanelLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void update(Graphics g) {
        revalidate();
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseWheelMoved(MouseWheelEvent e) {
        zoomer = true;
        if (e.getWheelRotation() < 0) {
            // Zoom in
            zoomFactor *= 1.1;
        } else if (e.getWheelRotation() > 0) {
            // Zoom out
            zoomFactor /= 1.1;
        }
        // Limit zoomFactor to maximum 5x and minimum 1x
        if (zoomFactor > 5.0) {
            zoomFactor = 5.0;
        } else if (zoomFactor < 1.0) {
            zoomFactor = 1.0;
        }

        xZoom = (int) (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX());
        yZoom = (int) (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY());
        // Ensure the parent container is updated
        repaint();

        this.callBack.execute();

    }

    @Override
    public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent e) {
        Point curPoint = e.getLocationOnScreen();
        xDiff = curPoint.x - startPoint.x;
        yDiff = curPoint.y - startPoint.y;
        dragger = true;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        released = false;
        startPoint = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
        released = true;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE) {
            reset();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void addNotify() {
        super.addNotify();
        requestFocusInWindow();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    private void updateInnerPanelLocation() {
        // Calculate the size of the innerPanel based on the zoom factor
        int innerPanelWidth = (int) (getWidth() * zoomFactor);
        int innerPanelHeight = (int) (getHeight() * zoomFactor);

        int xNewPoint = (int) (xZoom * zoomFactor);
        int yNewPoint = (int) (yZoom * zoomFactor);

        // Calculate the offset of the inner panel based on the zoom factor and mouse position
        int newX = (int) (xNewPoint - xZoom) * -1;
        int newY = (int) (yNewPoint - yZoom) * -1;

        int xCurrentMouse = (int) (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getX() - getLocationOnScreen().getX());
        int yCurrentMouse = (int) (MouseInfo.getPointerInfo().getLocation().getY() - getLocationOnScreen().getY());

        System.out.println("CurrentMouse" + xCurrentMouse + " : " + yCurrentMouse);
        System.out.println("NewMouse" + xNewPoint + " : " + yNewPoint);
        System.out.println("NewPos: " + newX + " : " + newY);
        // Set the new size and location of the inner panel
        innerPanel.setSize(innerPanelWidth, innerPanelHeight);

        innerPanel.setLocation((int) newX, (int) newY);
    }


    private void reset() {
        zoomFactor = 1;
        prevZoomFactor = 1;
        xOffset = 0;
        yOffset = 0;
        repaint();
    }

    private Container getTopLevelParent() {
        Container parent = getParent();
        while (parent != null && !(parent instanceof JFrame)) {
            parent = parent.getParent();
        }
        return parent;
    }

    @Override
    public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
        Color background = (Color) evt.getNewValue();
        setBackground(background);
        repaint();
    }
}


Class Parent Summary:
    public void panViewOneDevice() {
        JRootPane rootPane = getRootPane();
        rootPane.setBackground(Color.yellow);
        rootPane.updateUI();
        rootPane.revalidate();
        rootPane.invalidate();
        rootPane.repaint();

    }
...
ZoomableJPanel mainPanel = new ZoomableJPanel(panViewOneDevice, this::panViewOneDevice);
add(mainPanel);

The image is an innerPanel, and the green background is correctly positioned on the panel.
Let me know if you need any further adjustments or additional assistance! Thanks
